# Is it possible to create a custom CRS in QGIS that is not based on lat and long?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I would like to create a vector map of an indoor track in my living in the shape of the image below.

I am wondering if I can pick the top left corner as coordinate (0, 0) and define some value for width and height?

QGIS maybe not the best tool for this, but I want to pick it for personal reasons, specifically learning to write an API against the geo package.

[image]

The layers of the map would be the drivable space as well as the lane lines.

Comment: It's not possible, but you shouldn't care. You can lie the geographic location and the cartographic projection, if that doesn't matter to you. What you can't change on the map canvas is the direction of the vertical axis, so if you don't allow heights to be negative, you'll have to get used to seeing the image vertically flipped on the map.

Comment: If it's simple Cartesian units, that don't need to correspond to the real world, why would you need to use a custom CRS? Pick any existing CRS, and go with that.

Comment: @Vince but distances matter for localization. so how do I scale this map to any random CRS?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca the idea is to be able to create a baseline path around the track, from one road segment to the next in a counter clock wise fashion.  then the code on the robot car can generate a route plan using this and localize itself along the path

Comment: @Vince  I apologize, I probably should have added these details to the question

Comment: I can determine how far I have traveled along the path using simple kinematics, so it would be great to be able to have the baseline path also have the correct distance, in terms of how long a line segment is.

Comment: Your problem here is not creating a custom CRS but georeferencing the image to a CRS (any CRS) in appropriate ground units.